# C: Attempting to copy pointer values into another pointer, getting modifiable lvalue error

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am learning C and am getting stuck. Basically I have 2 arrays declared and I want to copy all of the char values of one array into the other by using pointers. I am taking advantage of the fact that the array name is a pointer to its first element. Could someone please take a look and help? Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *mystrcopy(char*p, char*q);   //function prototype

int main(void)
{
    char s1[20] = "Hello\n";   
    char s2[20] = "Bye\n";

    puts(s1);    //print Hello

    mystrcopy(s1, s2);  //call function using pointers s1 and s2

    puts(s1);   //I want this to print Bye after function has run

    system("pause");   //"press any key to continue...."

    return 0;
}

char *mystrcopy(char*s1, char*s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s1 + i; i++)    //for loop continues as long as s1+1 not 0
        s1 + i = s2 + i;   //error says s1 is not a modifiable lvalue

    return s1;   //I know this could be a void function but I choose not to
}
```

I thought this would be fine since (s1 + i) is a pointer pointing at the ith element in the array s1, and replacing it with the ith element in s2.

I tried using

*(s1+i) = *(s2+i)

instead, so copying the address of s2 into s1, but I get the same error.

EDIT:

The above code in the for loop actually worked

`*(s1+i) = *(s2+i)`

I think this didn't work because the loop that kept going. However, thanks everyone for answering my question on modifiable l value.

Comment: The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable.  Try using array notation to access the character you want, instead of attempting pointer arithmetic.

Comment: "s1+i" will evaluate to true until this expression evaluates to 0. Once you fix this compilation error, unless you fix this too, on a modern, 64 bit platform, this `for` loop will execute on average 9223372036854775808 times (by my calculations) which will take, ...a little while. Fortunately, it is going to crash much sooner than that. You need to explain precisely what you expect this function do, in order for anyone to help you with this problem, too.

Comment: maybe you forgot to fix the loop condition

Comment: Robert- thank you for your comment. I already did do this exercise using array notation. I just wanted to challenge myself using pointers.

Comment: Sam- thank you for your comment. Wow, what a big number. You are correct on this loop. I thought by looping it through s1, which is only 20 elements, the loop exits when it gets to the newline character at the end of the array, but I realized that is not zero. Thank you. Also, I explained what I want the code to do in the comments I left on the right of the code, most notably:                                         
           puts(s1);   //I want this to print Bye after function has run

Comment: M.M- thank you for your comment. It wasn't the loop problem that was causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you started. Notice we have to dereference the char* in the copy. This assumes fixed length strings and so doesn't need to use malloc nor strlen functions from std library. Not ideal but something you can play with to get going.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

    char *mystrcopy(char* p, char* q);   //function prototype

    #define LENGTH 20

    int main(void){

    char s1[LENGTH] = "Hello\n";   
    char s2[LENGTH] = "Bye\n";

    puts(s1);    //print Hello

    mystrcopy(s1, s2);

    puts(s1);   //I want this to print Bye after function has run

   // system("pause");   //"press any key to continue...."

    return 0;
}

char *mystrcopy(char* s1, char* s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++, ++s1, ++s2)    //for loop continues as long as s1+1 not 0
    *s1 = *s2;   //error says s1 is not a modifiable lvalue

    return s1;   //I know this could be a void function but I choose not to
```

}

Comment: You are god. Thank you so much. This definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since `s1` is a pointer, then `s1 + 1` is also yields a pointer too (just a temporary one whose address has been moved.

If we put some intermediary variables in place, then your loop is effectively going to be equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; s1 + i; i++)
{
    char* t1 = s1 + i;
    char* t2 = s2 + i;
    t1 = t2;
}
```

A major factor to note there is that it's not changing anything in the data being pointed to. It's only assigning the value of one pointer to another.

Now when taking a look back at `s1 + 1 = anything`, that's trying to assign something to a temporary pointer (not to what the temporary pointer points to). So the compiler complains as a safeguard because trying to assign to a temporary is always a mistake.

So knowing what you really wanted to do (and also noting that the loop condition of `s1 + 1` is not reading the value being pointed to, the code needs to be adjusted. For this type of situation, the array-like syntax allowed with pointers is much more convenient that trying to work in terms of incrementing the pointers themselves. Thus you would end up with something like:

```
for (i = 0; s1[i]; i++)
{
    s1[i] = s2[i];
}
```

---

As a bonus consideration, your logic copies from `s2` to `s1` but the loop is conditional on `s1`. So what is going to happen if initial data in `s1` is shorter than what is in `s2`? Perhaps your loop condition should be in terms of `s2`.

And a future consideration is what if the arrays pointed to be `s1` and `s2` aren't the same size. What kinds of problems can occur? Perhaps your function could take an additional parameter that specifies the maximum size of `s1`.

A final consideration is these kinds of things are where `std::string` makes it easier and safer than doing it yourself with `char` arrays.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your thoughtful and patient comment. You are so nice! The biggest takeaway I got is:


_A major factor to note there is that it's not changing anything in the data being pointed to. It's only assigning the value of one pointer to another._

This helped clarify this issue for me a lot. So even though I was changing the value of the pointer, if I went back and printed the s1 array itself, it wouldn't have done anything different if I didn't have the function at all. But what do you mean by *temporary* pointer? How was it temporary? Thank you very much.

Comment: @miltongoldman Say we had a line of code `a = b + c;` The compiler first calculates `b + c` and then hangs onto the result in a temporary manner. Next it assigns that temporary value to `a`. So consequently if we had `x + y = z;` The compilers first figures out what `x + y` is, hangs onto that as a temporary, and then... well, the problem is that the line of code isn't assigning `z` to either `x` or `y` but instead to the temporary combination of them - which isn't something a developer should have intended to do in the first place.